# Check if all std::tuple elements meet a condition + design concerns

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

So I am trying to validate if all elements of a `std::tuple` meet a certain condition. My current solution uses C++17 fold epxressions:

```
template <typename F, typename Tuple, size_t...Is>
_CR_INLINE bool tuple_all_of(F&& fn, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return (std::forward<F>(fn)(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))) && ...);
}

template <typename F, typename Tuple>
_CR_INLINE bool tuple_all_of(F&& fn, Tuple&& t) {
    return tuple_all_of(std::forward<F>(fn), std::forward<Tuple>(t), 
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>>());
}
```

It compiles in latest clang and gcc, but fails in MSVC, because fold expressions are not (yet) implemented. (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/)

So is there a similar solution without using fold expressions?

---

This is how it's supposed to be used:

```
template<typename...Components, typename Callable>
    void FindComponents(Callable&& fn) {
        for (auto& node : m_Entities) {
            auto tp = std::make_tuple(node.GetComponent<Components>()...);
            if (!tuple_all_of([](auto& p) { return p != nullptr; }, tp))
                continue;

            apply_from_tuple(fn, tp);
        }
    }
```

So I am calling `fn` only if a node has the requested components attached (i.e. `GetComponent` != nullptr). Maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: MSVC 2017.5 includes fold expressions as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Visual C++ Language Conformance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance) fold expressions are supported starting from VS2017 15.5 with `/std:c++17` (or `/std:c++latest`) compiler option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`std::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) to unpack the tuple more easily:

```
template <typename F, typename Tuple>
constexpr bool tuple_all_of(F&& fn, const Tuple& t)
{
    return std::apply([&fn](const auto&... xs)
    {
        return (fn(xs) && ...);
    }, t);
}
```

The *fold expression* can be replaced with [`for_each_argument`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2l83JlqkzBk):

```
template <typename F, typename Tuple>
constexpr bool tuple_all_of(F&& fn, const Tuple& t)
{
    bool result = true;
    std::apply([&](const auto&... xs)
    {
        for_each_argument([&](const auto& x)
        {
            if(fn(x)) result = false;
        }, xs...);
    }, t);
    return result;
}
```

```
template <class F, class... Ts>
void for_each_argument(F f, Ts&&... a)
{
    (void)std::initializer_list<int>{(f(std::forward<Ts>(a)), 0)...};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use the old trick of the initialization of a unused C-style array [caution: code not tested]

```
template <typename F, typename Tuple, size_t...Is>
_CR_INLINE bool tuple_all_of(F&& fn, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  using unused=bool[];

  bool ret { true };

  (void)unused { true, (ret = ret && std::forward<F>(fn)(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)))) ... };

  return ret;
}
```